# find a div and show

Tags: jquery

I have multiple div's with the same class that are on a page that are opened by another div that has the same class. Each time I try to open only one div, all the div's show because I am using a class. How would I write the jQuery to find the div to show and not show all the div's?

```
<div class="account">
 <div class="actions">
   <div><a href="" class="more">More Info</a></div>
 </div><!-- /actions -->
 <div class="info>This info would be show for more info</div>
</div><!-- /account -->

<div class="account">
 <div class="actions">
   <div><a href="" class="more">More Info</a></div>
 </div><!-- /actions -->
 <div class="info>This info would be show for more info</div>
</div><!-- /account -->
```

Comment: What div are you trying to show?  what have you done already that doesn't work?  what does your javascript look like?  a little more info would go a long way.

Comment: I don't know if this is your live code, but just FYI it's invalid, since the closing quote is missing off `class="info>`. This will introduce bugs in your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have your `.click` register find your `.info` element relative to `$(this)`

```
$(".more").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".account:first").find(".info").toggle();
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/cE8X6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.account a.more").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("div.info").show();
    return false;
});
```

This will show the "info" div that is inside the same "Account" div as the link.

For a more flexible, but less efficient approach, you could also do this:

```
$("div.account a.more").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div.account").first().children("div.info").show();
    return false;
});
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma28E/

Answer (score 0):

Either give each div a unique ID, or give them all more than  one class, so that the set of classes on any one div is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$('div.actions').find('a').click(function(e)
{
    $(this).parents('div.actions').next('.info').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to do:

```
$("a.more").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".account").find(".info").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

With the difference from the many other answers here being `closest` which finds the closest parent matching the selector. I prefer this to the `.parent().parent().parent()` approach as it gives the most flexibility for future markup changes. As long as there's a `.account` container with `.info` inside it, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Save this on a new file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#bt_action1").bind("click", function() {
                    $($(".account")[0]).toggle();
                })
                $("#bt_action2").bind("click", function() {
                    $($(".account")[1]).toggle();
                })
            }) 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="account">
            <div class="actions">
                <div><a href="" class="more">More Info 1</a></div>
            </div><!-- /actions -->
            <div class="info">This info would be show for more info</div>
        </div><!-- /account -->

        <div class="account">
            <div class="actions">
                <div><a href="" class="more">More Info 2</a></div>
            </div><!-- /actions -->
            <div class="info">This info would be show for more info</div>
        </div><!-- /account -->

        <form>
            <input type="button" id="bt_action1" value="Show/Hide 1" />
            <input type="button" id="bt_action2" value="Show/Hide 2" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key to this code is the change from Jquery object, to DOM object, to Jquery again, so you can find any div in the collection returned by the class selector:

```
$($(".account")[0]).toggle();
```

(Reminding that collections start with index `0`, so the second item has index `1` and so on. `toggle()` show or hide the div alternately).